# how can i make this into one div

Tags: asp.net, html, css

how can i make this in one div? currently it has two divs but i need to make it in one div like the images showing on the left and the text is on the right.

```
<div style='float: left; margin-left: 6px; margin-bottom: 6px; height: 191px;'>
    <img src='http://www.cnn.com/features/150px.jpg' width='100' height='100' border='0' alt='Lipsum' />
    <br /> 
    <img src='http://www.cnn.com/features/b150px.jpg' width='100' height='100' border='0' alt='Lipsum' />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
<div id='lipsum'>
    <p>first paragraph</p>
    <p>second paragraph</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: I only see one div there...

Comment: Can you expand on your question you are asking to make it one div but there is only one div tag used in this html

Comment: You shouldn't leech images from someone else's website like you are doing to CNN. (I am assuming you arent the developer for CNN's website). You shouldn't take their assets at all, but if you are really intent on it, at least save the image to your own server and load from there.

Comment: i updated my question, not sure what happend.

Comment: @jeff: take it easy it was just an example i was trying to demonostrate and fyi those links are not valid before you start giving me lecture.

Comment: @Abu Hamzah: I've edited your code to make it readable.  All the latin text was superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clear: left`:

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/FN4h4/

**CSS:**

```
img {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin: 0 6px
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id='lipsum'>

    <img src='http://www.cnn.com/features/150px.jpg' width='100' height='100' border='0' alt='Lipsum' />
    <img src='http://www.cnn.com/features/b150px.jpg' width='100' height='100' border='0' alt='Lipsum' />

    <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
</div>
```

Comment: just to let you know your images aren't coming up. Also another question. Would this work in IE7 - I've seen it have issues when you use a 'clear:' in the same css item as a `float`? (This is a curiosity question, not a hole pick)

Comment: how can i have a space between images, i just need the image where the paragraph starts

Comment: @My Head Hurts: I just used the images from the question. This should work just fine in IE7, as far as I know. I'm not familiar with any IE7 bug similar to your description.

Comment: @Abu Hamzah: I'm not sure what you're asking for. Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/FN4h4/1/ - or like this? http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/FN4h4/2/ - if not, you'll have to explain more clearly what you're after.

Comment: +1 - good solution, clearly defined. I got the wrong end of the stick I think and figured each image/paragraph pair was a separate article.

Answer (score 1):

no need for another div, give your image an align attribute, like

```
<img src='http://www.cnn.com/features/150px.jpg' width='100'
         height='100' border='0' alt='Lipsum' align="left"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to avoid using more than one `div`?  I'd do it something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="article">
    <img src="image1.jpg"/>
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
</div>
<div class="article">
    <img src="image2.jpg"/>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.article
{
    clear: both;
    width: 400px;
}
.article img
{
    float: left;
}
.article p
{
    float: right;
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/K2RQG/)

Comment: how can i have a space between images, i just need the image where the paragraph starts

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking why the img tags and the text nodes are in the same div (which is what it sounds like to me), its because you have all of the sub-nodes belonging to a single div node (id="div_left"). Html, Xml, and XHtml are all based upon a hierarchical node structure. Anything you want to separate into divs, to handle separate float rules for example, should be split into separate divs. You could still sub-node them into a parent div, but if you want to define individual styling you should explicitly put them into div or span tags.

For example, when I have different styling on multiple sub-nodes, I invariably use the template:

```
<div id="parentId">
    <div id="child1" />
    <div id="child2" />
</div>
```

Comment: I must add that I am a purist when it comes to separating content from style. As a Java developer, I think adherence to that basic principle creates flexibility in future development for a number of reasons, not the least of which being allowance of data extraction for porting to entirely new logic.